# Regex with @-sign not working

Tags: iphone, regex

I am using RegexKitLite in an iPhone project and want to use regex to find words that start with the `@`-sign. For instance, `"@home @chores"`, when searched, would return both words.

The regex string I am using is `"(?m-s:@.*\\s*)"`. When I use this, though, I get a crash. When I use the same thing, but with a `#` instead of `@`, it works just fine: "`(?m-s:#.*\\s*)"`. WTF?

I would much appreciate it if someone with a better understanding of regular expressions could help me on this. The tutorials I have seen so far have been near incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a modification of Manu's idea, just switching the location of the @ in the regex.

```
/(@\b\w+)/
```

I tested it on a string with '@foo @bar @baz @lol' and it seemed to do what you're looking for in matching on the words and capturing them with the parens.

Comment: You’re a genius! Thanks a lot!

Question: where can I find a really good regex tutorial? I never understand how you people come up with these regexes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `/\b@\w+/`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that:

```
NSString *search = @"This is my @home string with @some tokens to be @found";
NSString *regex = @"\\b@(\\w+)";
NSArray  *matches = NULL;

matches = [search componentsMatchedByRegex:regex];
// now matches should have { @"home", @"some", @"found" } values
```

I haven't tested that but should work.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. NSLog([matches description]); shows nothing.

Comment: Can you try escaping @ with double backslashes as well?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound too simple, but have you tried changing `@` to `\@` or `\\@`

Comment: Haha, that's the first thing I thought. Then I figured "no way, too simple" and deleted it...but since you're suggesting it too I don't feel as silly. Self-conciousness ftw.

Comment: I know nothing about how RegEx's work on the iPhone, but if there's a problem with just one character in a RegEx, escaping it is the first thing I try. ;)